# How can I compare "localeCompare" numbers?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have an error:

```
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _post1 $ _this3 $ selecte.localeCompare"
```

I understand post1 gets a number as an argument, but how can I compare "localeCompare" numbers?

```js
return [...this.posts].sort((post1, post2) => post1[this.selectedSort]?.localeCompare(post2[this.selectedSort]));
```

Comment: "_in promise_", are you sure `this` refers to what is intended?

Comment: it is a select button that selects sorting options, sorts by name and content as it should but an error occurs by id, as i understand it expects the number to be a string but i need localeCompare to work with numbers as well, or some other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I temporarily fixed the problem with the `if else` operator but leave the issue open as I want to optimize the feature in the future

```js
if(this.selectedSort == 'id'){
  return [...this.posts].sort((post1, post2) => post1[this.selectedSort] - post2[this.selectedSort]);
}
else{
  return [...this.posts].sort((post1, post2) => post1[this.selectedSort]?.localeCompare(post2[this.selectedSort]));
}
```

It worked for me !!!

```js
return [...this.posts].sort((post1, post2) => String(post1[this.selectedSort])?.localeCompare(String(post2[this.selectedSort]), 'en', {numeric: true}));
```

Comment: `localeCompare()` is a function on the string prototype, so maybe converting the numbers to string before comparing could work / not sure what you would like to achieve `post1[this.selectedSort]?toString().localeCompare(post2[this.selectedSort]`, but if your solution works, it looks good!

Comment: i tried to convert `this.selectedSort` to string before it reaches `localeCompare` but for some reason it didn't work and also broken the function for the string, that's why I was interested

Comment: I hope you don't believe ES6 syntactic sugar makes your code optimized, indeed, `[...this.posts]` can be slow https://javascript.plainenglish.io/es5-vs-es6-performance-comparisons-c3606a241633 ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use `localeCompare`, with numbers you can just use `sort((a, b) => a.x - b.x)` if you have an array of objects with a number property you want to use to sort.

For example

```js
const data = [{age: 12}, {age: 7}, {age: 18}];

const result = data.sort((a, b) => a.age - b.age);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: the problem is that i want to sort the string value with one function as well
ex : {"id": 2, "title": "..string..","body": "..string.."}